# UIWebView play audio when app goes to background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiwebview

I'm using YouTube iOS Helper Library to play a video inside a `WKWebView` and I want the audio to continue playing even when HOME is pressed or lock key.

Capabilities tab looks like this:

[image]

I have also imported `import AVFoundation` inside `AppDelegate`

and inside `func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)` I have this code:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch {
            // Handle setCategory failure
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

When app enters background audio stops and I can not even resume it from control center.

Comment: Pretty sure this is just a YouTube thing. What happens if you try a different website like Vimeo?

Comment: I'm using `youtube-player-ios-helper` not a website

Comment: I am trying to resolve the same problem too, with my own page in WKWebView using WebAudio APIs to produce sound. Every time the app goes into the background and later re-enters to the foreground, the WebAudio calls will all fail. I've tried calling AVAudioSession's setActive in applicationWillEnterForeground or applicationDidBecomeActive. Nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are searching for the similar solutions, want to tell, that play YouTube audio without displaying the video violates [the terms of services of YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) And your app will be rejected from App Store because of this.